# Set field value

Tags: netsuite

I have userevent script that I need to add a + 1 value to a field on edit.

This is what I have so far:

```
nlapiSubmitField('custbody1', + '1');
```

I am receiving an error, invalid expression. Please assist if you can.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`+ '1'` is not valid JavaScript syntax.

You will need to retrieve the current value from `custbody1` (presumably with a lookup), parse it as a `Number`, add `1` to the result, then that result is what you will pass to `nlapiSubmitField`.

Comment: The value in the field is 1, I need to add +1 to it. maybe, nlapigetfieldvalue('custbody1') then nlapisetfieldvalue('custbody1' + '/' 1) ?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to store the returned value of nlapiGetFieldValue in a variable before using nlapiSetFieldValue.  Something like:

```
var x = nlapiGetFieldValue('field1');
nlapiSetFieldValue('field1', parseInt(x) +1);
```